# Catch exception inside Linq

Tags: c#, linq, exception

I have this problem in my C#-code. I get an exception inside my Linq-code and would like to know how to catch it. *I have searched SO but cannot find any relevant issues.*

I have simplified my query to this:

```
var test = from values in myTable.AsEnumerable()
select new valueSet
{
    ID = values["ID"].ToString(),
    Number = values["Number"].ToString(),
    Name = this.getName(values["Number"].ToString()),
}
```

Since I get an exception inside the query when running the function ***getName*** I want to be able to catch the exception and also which ***Number*** I am currently at. Something like this:

```
try 
{           
    var test = from values in myTable.AsEnumerable()
    select new valueSet
    {
        ID = values["ID"].ToString(),
        Number = values["Number"].ToString(),
        Name = this.getName(values["Number"].ToString()),
    }
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //I want to use "Number" here!
    throw ex;
}
```

I am aware of that I declare my test-variable inside the try but can I for each "linq-loop" store the current Number? Any suggestions?

Comment: you can use `try...catch` inside `this.getName`

Comment: Why has this been downvoted twice? This question looks correct and interresting to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you will have to use the "other" LINQ syntax that uses extension methods and lambdas:

```
var test = myTable.AsEnumerable().Select(values =>
{
    try
    {
        return new valueSet
        {
            ID = values["ID"].ToString(),
            Number = values["Number"].ToString(),
            Name = this.getName(values["Number"].ToString()),
        };
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("cannot load number" + values["Number"].ToString());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick test to show what can work. Define a custom exception class:

```
public class MyException : Exception
{
    public MyException(TestClass testClass)
    {
        TestClass = testClass;
    }
    public TestClass TestClass { get; set; }
}
```

For demonstration, I use a custom `TestClass`, but this would be your table:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public int Id {get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set; }
}
```

Your `getName` operation would look like:

```
public static string getName(TestClass testClass)
{
        try
        {
            //functionality goes here
            throw new Exception(); // just for demo purposes, throw an exception here
            return testClass.Name;                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new MyException(testClass);
        }
}
```

And the main method that demonstrates how to catch the number:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<TestClass>() { new TestClass() { Id = 1, Name= "name", Number= 789} };
        try
        {
            var test = (from values in list
                       select new
                       {
                           Id = values.Id,
                           Name = getName(values),
                       }).ToList();
        }
        catch (MyException ex)
        {
            //I want to use "Number" here!
            var number = ex.TestClass.Number;
            throw ex;
        }  
    }
```

PS - don't mind the static keyword, this test was done in a console application.