# Why doesn't the catch statement catch all the exceptions?

Tags: c#, linq, exception

I'm testing the method below and I realized that when I enter wrong file name, the error gets caught but when I don't have an element on the position specified, the error of *IndexOutOfBounds* crashes the program. The latter goes also for converting errors.

```
private static IEnumerable<Thing> Initialize()
{
  try
  {
    string[] things = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("things.txt");
    return things.Select(_ => new Thing
    {
      Name = _.Split(';')[0],
      Id = Convert.ToInt32(_.Split(';')[0])
    });
  }
  catch(Exception exception)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
    return new List<Thing>();
  }
}
```

Why doesn't some errors get handled despite the most general *Exception* type in the *catch*? Does it have to do with LINQ expression failing? If so, how do I force the catching, then?

Comment: Are you sure the exception happens *within* the `try` block shown?

Comment: It should catch it. I am not able to reproduce the error you are getting. I tested your code having `things` equal to `new string[0]`.

Comment: [A Minimal, complete and verifiable example would really help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23782430/catch-exception-inside-linq. The posted answers are correct -- this is because of deferred execution, i.e. the exception doesn't occur until after the method returns, so the try/catch is no longer present. But there are already plenty of Q&As on SO addressing this issue.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, I did. But I get no errors because the array I used is empty and thus nothing was executed. I think that it is a specific input that is causing the error for OP.

Comment: @Fabjan Hard to do because it includes the file. But I do have a short CS-snippet that verifies the error. However, it's been already answered where I got wrong.

Comment: @YacoubMassad As the answer state - the issue is that with the deferred execution. It means you have to have some elements in the array **and** try to access them.

Comment: @KonradViltersten, right

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because you return IEnumerable.
The lambda inside Select doesn't execute immediately, but only on accessing the enumerable (iterating items).

If you add call "ToArray" after "Select" then all items will be calculated and IndexOutRangeException will be catched in your catch block.

```
return things.Select(_ => new Thing
{
  Name = _.Split(';')[0],
  Id = Convert.ToInt32(_.Split(';')[0])
}).ToArray();
```

Comment: I thought that even though we have lazy execution, the code would jump into the LINQ query and be caught there. I prefer not to generate the whole sequence right away. Is there another way to force the thing to be catchable?

Comment: @Konrad: _"Is there another way to force the thing to be catchable?"_ -- if you want to catch the exception then you need to put a try/catch in the selector lamba itself, or put a try/catch around whatever code actually _evaluates_ the `IEnumerable<T>` that's being returned. This is described in detail in the many identical questions already posted on Stack Overflow.

Comment: "Is there another way to force the thing to be catchable?" 
@Konrad Viltersten, If you want to keep the existing catching behavior (return empty list in case of any exceptions) then it's logically impossible without iterating the whole input array. If you want to just skip the invalid items, then you may use "yield" operator for generating IEnumerable.

Comment: Funny. That's what I ended up doing **bero** I saw your comment. As I said - great minds think alike.   :)

Answer (score 5):

You are returning an `IEnumerable<>` which implies deferred execution.
So anything inside the lambda is actually executing later, outside the try/catch.

If you want to catch all errors, include a `.ToList()` , like

```
 return things.Select(...).ToList();
```

Comment: I thought that even though we have lazy execution, the code would jump into the LINQ query and be caught there when trying to iterate to next element of the *IEnumerable*. Sneaky LINQy...   :)

Comment: It's tempting to read it that way but the try/catch is on a stack frame that's already gone when the results are gotten.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this a couple of years ago, and the explanation I found online is that it is because of unmanaged assemblies and code. Something that is out of the application domain. Mostly when you have a lower level (os level) operation

Comment: I guess, you are talking about "Corrupted State Exceptions", but it has no relation to this particular question